# Problem with using delimiters in C with fscanf

Tags: c, scanf, csv

So lets say I have a line of text in a txt file (e.g. 1234567890 DD.M.YYYY. hh:mm NAMEOFHALL) and i have around 2000 of said lines. I would like to use fscanf to pull out "1234567890", ""DD.M.YYYY", "HH:MM" and "NAMEOFHALL" as separate strings (note: NAMEOFHALL does not have a fixed length, it can vary from something short as A203 to FSB HALL B).

Here's the bit of code I'm using for scanning and seeing how the 4 separate strings look like:

```
while(i<lines){
    fscanf(fp,"%11[^ ] %10[^ ] %5[^ ] %[^\n]", polaznik[i].jmbag, polaznik[i].datum, polaznik[i].vrijeme, polaznik[i].dvorana);
    printf("%s#%s#%s#%s\n",polaznik[i].jmbag, polaznik[i].datum, polaznik[i].vrijeme, polaznik[i].dvorana);
    i++;  
}
```

where fp is a pointer to the .txt file

You can see the full code [here](https://pastebin.com/NwNhY1Nf).

I used hashtags in printf because I thought that there were some stray space characters in the read but there are not any.

I am expecting an output from the printf like:

> 0246694342#25.1.2014.#12:16#FSB Dvorana C

But instead I get:

> 0246694342FSB Dvorana C#25.1.2014.#12:16#FSB Dvorana C

Also please refrain from subtly roasting me as I am doing this on low energy and I'm more prone to miss obvious mistakes that way.

Thanks to anyone that replies.

Comment: Your `jmbag` member will only hold 10-chars + the terminator, so that `%11[^ ]` is a lie. In format string extractions, length-modifiers should always be at least one *less* than the target buffer size accommodation to account for the terminator addition. That differs from `fgets`, whose size argument expects the full buffer size (i.e. the entire buffer size in octets). Anyway, keep an eye on that. Frankly, i don't know why you're not you're using `fgets`, `strtok`, etc, to do this. It's much safer, and a helluvalot less complicated, imho.

Comment: Post the definition of `polaznik` here.  Links to other places tend to disappear.

Comment: char jmbag[11];char dvorana[15];
    char datum[11];
    char vrijeme[6];